# How to install PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, qt

I need to install pyqt5 on raspberry pi that has Rapbian on itself. please help me how to do that

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: this link https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/wiki/Compiling-PyQt5-on-Ubuntu-12.04  training how to install PyQt on ubuntu. can I use this link to install PyQt on Raspberry?